# About Sockets in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I just wanted to know if there is a way to connect two computers that both of them are behind two different routers without port forwarding via the socket class in as3??

Comment: Its possible but You have to create AIR application , than You can use ServerSocket class to setup TCP server and listen for incomming Sockets connections .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly without having a server side component.

I suggest you get some info about Adobe Cirrus 
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/

Comment: I've just figured it out, I can do this by simply using UDP instead of TCP